# Where is the bootstrap-sass color codes?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.0). I was following a tutorial and I used the following code in `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss`.

```
.timestamp {
    color: $grayLight;
}
```

The result was an error indicating that undefied valuable $grayLight. And I found [a link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/463) says the naming has changed from $grayLight to $gray-light.

I sought on the internet for the documentation regarding to the defined colors but I failed to found it. I think this kind of documentation should exist. Totally no idea which color code can be used.

Even I used `find . -type f -exec grep -H "gray-light" {} \;` there is no such file defines the color code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure you're browsing the gem source... `bundle open bootstrap-sass`. Then browse to: *vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss*

Reproducing the relevant section here for your convenience:

```
//== Colors
//
//## Gray and brand colors for use across Bootstrap.

$gray-darker:            lighten(#000, 13.5%) !default; // #222
$gray-dark:              lighten(#000, 20%) !default;   // #333
$gray:                   lighten(#000, 33.5%) !default; // #555
$gray-light:             lighten(#000, 60%) !default;   // #999
$gray-lighter:           lighten(#000, 93.5%) !default; // #eee
```

Note: this is from bootstrap-sass v3.1.0.2 so may have changed in 3.2.0.0 somewhat.

I find the bootstrap-sass gem's SCSS files very easy to read so I jump into the source on this one quite often. Good luck!